# Solving $n\log{n}=10^9$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The logarithm here is of base $2$. I tried to solve the following equation to find out $n$, where $n \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$n\log{n}=10^9$$

**Edited:** My naive approach was to raise both sides to exponential $2$,

$$2^{n\log{n}}=2^{10^9}$$
$$2^{\log{n^n}}=2^{10^9}$$
$$n^n=2^{10^9}$$

I got stuck here. I saw another solution suggesting to use Lambert $W$ function,

$$n=\frac{10^9\times \log{2}}{W(10^9\times \log{2})}$$

**Question 1:** Can you please tell me if it's possible to solve it without Lambert function as I did? But I got stuck at $n^n=2^{10^9}$, so how to proceed from here?

**Question 2:** How the solution that used Lambert $W$ function get to that factor $n=\frac{10^9\times \log{2}}{W(10^9\times \log{2})}$?

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be an integer here, as the discrete-mathematics tag might suggest?

Comment: @TheoBendit. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: You have a mistake in your approach. It should be $n^n = 2^{10^{9}}$.

Comment: "Can you please tell me if it's possible to solve it without Lambert function as I did? "  No not really.

Comment: @LarsSmith. Thank yo. How did you get $n^n$?

Comment: @fleablood. Thank you. How to do it then using Lambert function?

Comment: What you did could be done if it was $2^{n+\log_2n}$. Here we have $2^{n\log_2n} = (2^{\log_2n})^n = n^n$. Also note that $n\log_2n = \log_2n^n$.

Comment: @LarsSmith. Thanks! Corrected. So, how to solve $n^n = 10^9$ afterwards?

Comment: As fleablood stated it cannot be solved algebraically, at least I don't know such a way.

Comment: @LarsSmith. I got it, thanks. How to get the quantity $n=\frac{10^9\times \log{2}}{W(10^9\times \log{2})}$?

Comment: I haven't watched it yet but I believe this video of blackpenredpen explains it well. https://youtu.be/Qb7JITsbyKs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambert $W(M)$ is by definition the unique real solution of $x$ if $xe^x =M$.

If we have to solve $w^w = K$ and $w> 0$ we can use this to solve

$$\ln w^w = \ln K$$

$$w\ln w = \ln K$$

$$e^{\ln w} \ln w = \ln K$$

$$\ln w = W(\ln K)$$

$$w = e^{W(\ln K)}$$

We are almost done but $e^{W(****)}$ is considered not simplified enough.

Note by definition that $W(M) e^{W(M)} = M$ we will always have $e^{W(M)} = \frac M{W(M)}$.  And that is considered simplified enough.

$$w = \frac {\ln K}{W(\ln K)}$$

.....

So a general solution:

> $w^w =K$ has solution $w = \frac {\ln K}{W(\ln K)}$.

Now your problem is:

$$n\log_2 n = 10^9$$

$$2^{n\log_2 n} = 2^{10^9}$$

$$n^n = 2^{10^9}$$

So $n = \frac {\ln (2^{10^9})}{W(\ln (2^{10^9}))} = \frac {10^9\ln 2}{W(10^9\ln 2)}$

Comment: Could you please explain as to why $W(M) e^{W(M)} = M$ since as you mentioned $w e^{w} = K$, then $w=W(ln(K))$.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to avoid Lambert, here is a strategy to get close to the solution.

You may know $2^{10}=1024\approx10^3$. From this it seems $2^{30}\approx10^9$. So lets look at $$x\log x=2^{30}$$ Note this $x$ will be larger than the original $n$ we are looking for. If $x=2^k$, then $$k2^k=2^{30}$$ $$\log k+k=30$$ We know $\log16+16=20$ and $\log32+32=37$ So in the solution, $\log k$ is between 4 and 5. We pretend linearity to take $\log k\approx4+\frac{10}{17}$. Then $$k\approx25+\frac{7}{17}$$ $$n\approx x\approx2^{25+7/17}$$

A calculator check gives $$\left(2^{25+7/17}\right)\log\left(2^{25+7/17}\right)\approx 1.134\cdot10^9$$ From here, putzing around with the exponent can show $$\left(2^{25+1/4}\right)\log\left(2^{25+1/4}\right)\approx 1.0075\cdot10^9$$

Comment: Thank you. Answer I got was $3.96201 \times 10^7$

Comment: I don't understand this part: $k\approx25+\frac{7}{17}$$ $$n\approx x\approx2^{25+7/17}$. I got it when you said that $\log(k)$ is between 4 an 5, but I did not  get what you did afterwards.

Comment: The difference between $20$ and $37$ is $17$. Our target is $30$, which is $\frac{10}{17}$ of the way between $20$ and $37$. So it's a rough estimate that we should end up with $\log k$ being $\frac{10}{17}$ of the way between $4$ and $5$. So I have $\log k\approx4+\frac{10}{17}$. (I had omitted the "log" from this statemnt, but just edited to put it in.) Then $\log k+k\approx30$ becomes $4+\frac{10}{17}+k\approx30$, from which $k\approx25+\frac{7}{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

You could try fixed point iteration and the error of $s_n$ to $10^9$ is tiny after just a few iterations:
$$
x_1=2\\
x_{n+1}\gets \log_2(10^9/x_n)\\
s_n=10^9 /x_n\\ 
s_\infty\log_2(s_\infty)=10^9
$$

```
8.66671*10^8, 1.00824*10^9, 9.99531*10^8, 1.00003*10^9, 9.99998*10^8
```

This works because the Lambert function can be written this way if $|W(x)|>e$:
$$
W(x)=\ln \frac{x}{\ln \frac{x}{\ddots}}
$$
...so we're still technically using Lambert but the iterative version might be useful if you don't have a Lambert function on your calculator or in a mathematics software library.